# What is the purpose of ϵ-transitions in PDA?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

$A = \{a^i b^j c^k\mid i = j\text{  or } j = k; i, j, k \ge 0\}$. 
In its push down automaton should not there be the red colored transition instead of the black colored[image] one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could substitute the red transition for the black one below and have an equivalent PDA. With the black one, you allow the possibility that when reading $\mathtt{b}$s, you make a nondeterministic switch to the state where you expect to see a $\mathtt{c}$. If you do, it's as if you followed the red transition. In other words, either PDA will accept a string in $A$.

By the way, you could do a similar thing between the first and the second states of the upper branch.

The moral is that here are many roads to the top of the mountain, grasshopper.

Answer (score 1):

You may notice that when $i=j=k=0$ you get the empty word, which is
thus in the language. Hence, you need to accept the empty
word. Allowing to reach a final state without ever reading anything is
one way to accept the empty word, and it is here easily achieved with
the $\epsilon$-transitions.

You may also note how $\epsilon$-transitions are convenient to
actually produced the PDA as the "union"of two PDAs.

Actually, it is a convenient way to allow any of $i,j,\text{ and }k$
to be $0$.

Of course, there are other ways to get this result, without
$\epsilon$-transitions. But the automaton may be more complicated.
Such variation on how to write automata do not always change the
family of languages, but may help to write more natural or intuitive
descriptions.

**Regarding your example, and the transition in red.**

*The transition in red cannot replace the $\epsilon$-transition between
the same states.*

If you take $i=3, j=0,\text{ and }k=0$, you have the string $a^3$
which is in the language, but is not accepted by the modified
automaton.

It cannot be accepted by the upper part of the automaton which
acceptes only when $i=j$.

It cannot be accepted by the bottom part of the automaton since the
accepting state can be reached only by scanning a $c$, and there is
none when $j=k=0$.

With the the black $\epsilon$-transition, reading a $c$ is optional, while it
becomes compulsory with the red transition.